# how to set ImageView visible through out the android application for header

Tags: android

I have a header design which contains an ImageView and it is common for all the layouts in my application. I want to set the ImageView visible onclick of some button. The ImageView must visible in all the activities. I am using `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` but its not working for all the activities.

Comment: use fragments, or a static variable which will be set on onClick of the button and will be checked for in onCreate of all activities to determine whether to make it visible or not

Comment: are you including the same header xml for all activities?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement this task. One of the easy task is to implement a common header by using **ViewStub**. Follow below steps:

1. Define header.xml with ImageView or any other widgets.
2. Now take ViewStub inside the layouts of other activity's xml layout for example: main.xml

   ```
   <!-- Included header.xml here -->
   <ViewStub android:id="@+id/vsHeader" 
       android:inflatedId="@+id/header" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout="@layout/header" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/txtDemo" />
   ```
3. Define one BaseActivity class from where you can control the visibility of ImageView.

   ```
   abstract public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

   protected View header;
   protected View footer;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   }

       @Override
   public void setHeader(Activity activity, boolean visible) {
       if (visible) {
           activity.findViewById(R.id.vsHeader).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           header = findViewById(R.id.header);
                } else
           activity.findViewById(R.id.vsHeader).setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now extends this BaseActivity to all other your Activity, so that you can access those methods.

So in 3rd step above, you can call setHeader() method with true/false as a visible value. You can check detailed example here: [Android – ViewStub example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-viewstub-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class say "MyHeaderVisibility" that holds a static boolean variable say "imagevisibility". Set visibility of the header image for all activities dependent on this boolean variable. You should be good to go.

```
    class MyHeaderVisibility{
            static boolean imagevisibility = false;
    }
```

On a button click event' you can change the visibility by:

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    MyHeaderVisibility.imagevisibility = true;
            }
    }
```